# USB type C power

Tags: voltage, usb

I use a USB cable (normal type A male on one end) and type C on the other.
I connect the C end to my Samsung tablet and the other end into my DJI Mavic drone remote controller.  The connection works, but my tablet shows it is charging the battery - obviously off the RC controller, which has a much smaller battery than the tablet.  Is it possible for me to open the cable up and cut the power wires so just that data goes back and forth between the two devices.

I am not an electrical engineer, so please bear with me on this ...
Thanks in advance ...
Ron

Comment: Could you post a link to your specific controller? Simple search says that it doesn't have Type-A standard USB receptacle. So it is not clear how can you use the standard Type-A-Type-C cable.

Comment: This question isn't about computer hardware or software, and it really actually DOES appear to be a much better fit for Electronics SE, who booted it. However, because it was booted from its best home, I suggest we leave it here for now. It's a VERY interesting question with application to laptops as many of these are going to USB-C connectors for their charging, and I'd imaging they'd probably have similar issues were they in the place of the tablet here.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. The Tablet is Type-C product (and likely having Dual-role Type-C USB port), it should follow Type-C protocol for detection of cable, aka "Detection of Valid Source-to-Sink Connection". Unlike older USB2, the Type-C cable detection on device side doesn't require the VBUS to be present, all detection comes from Pu/Pd on CC wire/pins. However, the  presence of Source (DJI controller in this case) is still determined when the VBUS goes active on source side. Therefore, cutting the VBUS power between DJI Controller and Samsung Tablet will likely lead to no connection.

This situation seems to be a loophole in Type-C specifications. But there might be some hope. Device firmware that controls all Type-C functionality is written by people, and people might have some open interpretation of what to do with VBUS upon connect. So it is not a given that cutting the VBUS won't work. Why don't you just try your idea? Cables are not that expensive...

More, after you cut the cable and if it doesn't work, you may try to fool the Tablet into thinking that the source of VBUS is very weak. Try to cut the red wire, but put, say, a 1 kOhm resistor into the cut, in series. I expect the Tablet will try the source capability (it should try 500 mA as from a standard USB port), and the VBUS will drop. So the Tablet should assume it can't use its charge function. But this is just an idea. Let the SE EE community know how it ends up.